# jQuery split paragraph text inside <br> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div

```
<div class="address"><p>Test User<br>I. zone<br>Test street<br>3<br>11012</p></div>
```

I can select this text like this in jQuery

```
var fulline = $("div.address>p").text();
```

or

```
var fulline = $("div.address>p").html();
```

My question is how can I split this line to get a String like this:

> I. zone Test street 3 11012

Comment: So, you don't want the first text `Test User` ?

Comment: What is the logic behind the nodes you do/do not want to include. Is it just that you want to grab the All nodes except the first?

Comment: Split the string on `"<br>"`, remove the first element then join what's left.

Comment: @gurvinder372
Yes and replace the `<br>` tags with whitespaces

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's a backend generated line and I need this string to enter in a Google maps search box which shows the address on page load

Comment: If it's generated from the backend could you not amend that code to output the value in the format you require in a `data` attribute. That way you don't need to use JS as a crutch for your UI, and all data presentation logic is in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use: `fulline.split("<br>").slice(1).join(" ")`

**Demo**

```js
var fulline = $("div.address > p").html();

console.log(fulline.split("<br>").slice(1).join(" "))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="address">
  <p>Test User<br>I. zone<br>Test street<br>3<br>11012</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `shift` and `join`

```
var html = document.querySelector( ".address p" ).innerHTML;

var tmpItems = html.split( "<br>" );
tmpItems.shift();

console.log( tmpItems.join(" ") );
```

**Demo**

```js
var html = document.querySelector( ".address p" ).innerHTML;

var tmpItems = html.split( "<br>" );
tmpItems.shift();

console.log( tmpItems.join(" ") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="address"><p>Test User<br>I. zone<br>Test street<br>3<br>11012</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. Read the comments to get better insight of what is going on.

```js
//get the html content of <p>
var fulline = $("div.address>p").html();
//split it using <br> so that you get an array
var res = fulline.split("<br>");
//remove the first element that contain 'Test User'
res = res.slice(1);
//join the array element using a space
res= res.join(" ");
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="address"><p>Test User<br>I. zone<br>Test street<br>3<br>11012</p></div>
```